# "This page can’t be displayed" when trying to activate RedGate Multiscript

Tags: redgate

I'm trying to activate my multiscript on a server but it just doesnt allow me.

I open Multiscript > login > user and pass > then the error "This page can’t be displayed" appears.

`URL: http://127.0.0.1:port/dialog/views/completeLogin.html?connectionId=eajwlssdsdsdy&displayName=MYnAME&authorizationToken=TOKENS.`.

```
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:22223 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

we tried everything, lowering secutiry on internet explorer and nothing works.

I could activate it on my own machine with no problems, so I know its some config issue that I cant find.

Answer (score 1):

after so so so many hours, I got the link that was giving me the error, opened an internet explorer as admin and copied it.

success!